# Modify featured image path to Amazon S3

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, amazon

I have uploaded my images to Amazon S3. There are some featured images. In order to modify their path, I run the update scripts to change the path of `wp_posts.guid`. But the image still points to the old path.

How can I change the featured image url so as to point to the Amazon S3 path?

Thanks

Comment: Does it mean you have moved you upload folder to Amazon or only a few images?

Comment: Could you use the `post_thumbnail_html` filter?

Comment: I have uploaded all images to s3 . I need the image src to fetch from the amazon s3 url instead of old path. <a href="<?php the_permalink(); //show permalink?>">
                                    <?php 
                                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                                      the_post_thumbnail();
                                    }</a>                                                 How shall I modify the above code to change the image source url?Can it be done via db scripts?

Comment: Check out [WP Offload S3](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/).

Answer (score 2):

You can hook into the output and modify the URL there.

```
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 5 );

function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr ) {

  $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
  $base_url = $upload_dir['baseurl'];

  // Change the default upload directory to AWS Bucket link
  $AWSBucket = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket';
  $html = str_replace($base_url, $AWSBucket, $html);

  return $html;
}
```

Output the image

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail ();
```

Reference:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_thumbnail_html/
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to point the uploads folder to the same location. You can do it by making the below changes in the `wp-config.php` file

Open up your wp-config.php file, located at the root of your WordPress installation, and add the following code:

```
define('UPLOADS', 'http://amazon_url/uploads'); //Replace the url here with folder in Amazon
```

The codex specifies that it should be added before the line that says require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);.

Make sure the **uploads folder is writable.**

Comment: Thanks.The above helps to point the existing images to s3 path.But while trying to upload a new image,it gives error "Unable to create directory /wp-content/uploads/2009/mydir/summer/ Is its parent directory writable by the server?".If I comment the code added in config file, it is getting uploaded to s3. I am using wordpress plugin "Amazon S3 and  cloudfront".

Comment: Hi,In addition the doc saysThis path can not be absolute. It is always relative to ABSPATH              http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_uploads_folder. Therefore,can we give the http path as above?

Comment: yes you can, esp when you have the uploads folder in a separate domain. please make  sure the folder is writable to make this work and upload further