# Retrieving Image Storage path

Tags: images

```
$attachment_id = 8; // attachment ID
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ); // returns an array
```

Could you please specify which database table is referred for to retrieve the image source url?

Answer (score 0):

Images (and all other attachments) are associated with a post in the `posts` table. The attachment source URL is saved in the `guid` column.

[image]

That’s not a good choice, because sooner or later GUIDs won’t follow the URL scheme anymore, so don’t query that field directly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If I upload all the media files to amazon s3 and modify the guid path, will it then point to new amazon path like below? UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013',
'http://test.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2013');

Comment: In case you are moving all your images/upload folder to amazon, you need to make a small change in the **wp-config.php** file to make it work.
Follow the link for details http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120326/modify-featured-image-path-to-amazon-s3/120342#120342

Comment: @user40991 How the URL is stored for external services depends on the plugin you are using for that.